Django test database configuration for unittest
I am running unittest with coverage command but having trouble with test database interaction.
Here is my code snippet.
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.models import Animal


class AnimalTestCase(TestCase):
    databases = {'default', 'read_replica'}
    def setUp(self):
        Animal.objects.create(name="lion", sound="roar")
        Animal.objects.create(name="cat", sound="meow")

    def test_animals_can_speak(self):
        """Animals that can speak are correctly identified"""
        all_animals = Animal.objects.all()
        print(all_animals)

If I run this code and try to print all animals in the database, it only prints the animals in the real database and not prints Animals like lion and cat.
I think this might be related to the database configuration.
I tried to use this configuration in the settings.py.
from django.test import override_settings
@override_settings(DATABASES={
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": "db.sqlite3",
        "TEST": {
            "NAME": "mytest.sqlite3",
        }
    },
    "read_replica": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
        "NAME": "db.sqlite3",
        "TEST": {
            "NAME": "mytest.sqlite3",
        }
    },
})

but this is still not working.
My expectation is to interact with test database so based on my code snippet, I want to print lion and cat.

I believe Django, will create a testing database by itself based on the migrations. Please take a look at this, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database
Also override_settings is a decorator, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
